# command "python3 app.py db migrate" but server is running, not migrating

Tags: flask, model, python-3.7, migrate

Experts!

I am a beginner in Flask.

I have any project and it includes some models(already defined).

This is one of my models and these are placed as other files, not in app.py.

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, SmallInteger, String, Text, Date, Boolean, Float

class CategoryTopicLink(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'category_topic_link'

    id                         = Column(Integer, primary_key=True) 
    category_id                = Column(Integer)
    topic_id                   = Column(Integer)
```

And I am going to migrate these by running app.py.
So I inputted some code in app.py and my app file look at following:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, make_response

...

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from flask_migrate import Migrate

app = Flask(__name__)

CORS(app)

api = Api(app)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

migrate = Migrate(app, db)

from .models import CategoryTopicLink

........

if __name__=="__main__":

    app.run(debug=True,host="127.0.0.1",port="5001")
```

And To migrate model I commanded

- "python3 app.py db init" (but server run)
- "python3 app.py db migrate" (also server run, not migrate)
- "flask run db init" (error - flask has not db attribute)
- "flask run db migrate" (error - flask has not db attribute)
  ......

Please let me know how to migrate models.

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards, from jis0324!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commands are always in the form

```
flask db command
```

Also see the manual

https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Hi, J.G. Thanks for your reply.
Yeah, ""flask db init"" and "flask db migrate" works and make migrations folder. I appreciate for these.
But I can't find the tables from datatable. In other short, models didn't be migrated in the table.